# how to access an excel file in c#

Tags: c#

I need to open an excel sheet from a particular location (`d:\temp\emp.xls`) and then bold the  column headers and save the file.

I am trying to  do it   but  not getting how  to open the file  and access the 1 row  and make them as bold in c#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp)

Comment: I have imported the data using the SSIS packages now the excel sheet contains the data. now i am writing an script task  so that i can access the  file change the column width and  make them bold

Answer (score 0):

string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; data source=c:\customers.xls; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

```
  // Select using a Named Range
  //string selectString = "SELECT * FROM Customers";

  // Select using a Worksheet name
  string selectString = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";

  OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
  OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(selectString,con);

  try
  {
    con.Open();
    OleDbDataReader theData = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (theData.Read())
    {
      Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} ({2}) - {3} ({4})", theData.GetString(0),theData.GetString(1),theData.GetString(2),theData.GetString(3),theData.GetString(4));
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
  }
  finally
  {
    con.Dispose();
  }
```