# Save an Excel file in C#

Tags: c#, excel

```
  void excelsave()
  {
      try
      {
          ApplicationClass app = new ApplicationClass(); // the Excel application.

          Workbook book = null;
          Worksheet sheet = null;
          Range range = null;
          // the range object is used to hold the data
          app.Visible = false;
          app.ScreenUpdating = false;
          app.DisplayAlerts = false;

          string execPath =
            Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);

          book = app.Workbooks.Open(@"E:\SSIS\ABC\Book1.xls",
               Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
               Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
               Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
               Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
          sheet = (Worksheet)book.Worksheets[1];

          range = sheet.get_Range("A1", Missing.Value);
          range.Columns.ColumnWidth = 22.34;
          range = sheet.get_Range("B1", Missing.Value);
          range.Columns.ColumnWidth = 22.34;
          book.SaveAs(@"E:\SSIS\ABC\Book1.xls", Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {

       }
 }
```

Here I am opening an Excel sheet trying to increase the column width and need to make the column headers as bold and save the document. Right now, the document is not getting saved. I am using VS 2008 and C# 3.5.

Is there anything that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: you could start by logging any exceptions rather than ignoring them all in that empty catch block!

Comment: Show us your ex.Message and ex.StackTrace, assuming it's raising an exception.

Comment: You better stop using `Interop` and start using `excel-automation`. Is your application a `web-application`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to access an excel file in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869909/how-to-access-an-excel-file-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 10):

I ran the following using VS 2010 and .NET 4, but this code should still work in your environment.  Also, I simplified your code a bit.  Hopefully this will get you going in the right direction.

```
    static void excelsave()
    {
        try
        {
            Application app = new Application();
            string execPath =
              Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);

            Workbook book = app.Workbooks.Open(@"c:\test.xls");
            Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)book.Worksheets[1];

            Range range = sheet.get_Range("A1");
            range.Columns.ColumnWidth = 22.34;
            range = sheet.get_Range("B1");
            range.Columns.ColumnWidth = 22.34;

            sheet.get_Range("A1", "B1").Font.Bold = true;

            book.SaveAs(@"c:\test2.xls");  // or book.Save();
            book.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

You can find a similar explanation/example of what you are doing at:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel

```
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(book);  // do this after the close
```

Also, there is a good discussion on cleaning up Excel/COM ...
[How To Properly Clean Up Excel Interop Objects In c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects-in-c-sharp)